# How I can use bootstrap datepicker with year and month drop down option, as well as with the min date and max date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, calendar

I need a bootstrap datepicker where the start date and enddate must be customizable like start date is 01-01-1950 and end date is todate-18 years. Secondly wanted to show the dropdown year and month on the calendar topbar to use easily rather than the default bootstrap calendar.

For your reference have attached an image which 'm using now without bootstrap.

[image]

Any idea/link is appreciated.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: Now we are using bootstrap4 datepicker but year and month drop down is not happening

Answer (score 1):

you can not put dropdown but can achieve same functionality by another way with new bootstrap version.
check out this link http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: But there is no way to use dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date_deb').daterangepicker({locale: {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}, 
      showDropdowns: true,
      minDate: '01/01/2016',
      singleDatePicker: true,
      singleClasses: "picker_2"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    });
  });
</script>
```